# Inserir dados no banco ultilizando mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Como faço para inserir esses dados no banco ultilizando `mysqli`:

```
print $data->access_token."<br />";
print $data->username."<br />";
print $data->full_name."<br />";
print $data->id."<br />";

...

$conexao = mysql_connect($localhost, $usuario, $senha) or die();
$select =mysql_select_db($bancodedados) or die();
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `usuarios` () VALUES()");
```

Estou tentando (de acordo com a sugestão do @perdeu):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','instagram');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO instagram (acess_token, username, full_name, id) values(?,?,?,?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $data->acess_token, $data->user->username, $data->user->full_name
, $data->user->id   );
$stmt->execute();
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a  
non-object in C:\wamp\www\instagram\example\success.php on line 30  
Call Stack  
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0020  146880  {main}( ) ..\success.php:0
```

Comment: Isso não é `mysqli`, é `mysql` mesmo... (veja que está faltando o "i" após "mysql" em todas as chamadas) E - como apontado nas respostas - esse tipo de conexão está obsoleta (*deprecated*), usar PDO seria preferível. Não posso falar sobre o mysqli entretanto, pois não tenho experiência.

Comment: Eu não percebi se queres saber como se faz a query sql ou como se aplica essa query com PHP (mysqli)

Comment: Se você quiser alterar, melhorar ou atualizar sua pergunta não crie uma resposta. O melhor a fazer é editar seu post, para colocar os detalhes extras. Se voce resolver o problema da sua pergunta mas ele levar à uma nova dúvida, não há problema em criar uma nova pergunta (pode até mesmo fazer referência à sua pergunta anterior, para dar um contexto).

Comment: Tem algum erro na sua consulta, para exibir-lo use esse código: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
 if($stmt == ''){ 
    echo $mysqli->error;
 }`

Answer (score 7):

Para utilizar o mysqli com prepared statements é o seguinte código:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','usuario','senha','base');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) values(?,?,?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $variavel1, $variavel2, $varivavel3);
$stmt->execute();
```

os três `s` no `bind_param()` significam o tipo de dado passado que podem ser:

```
s: para 'string'
i: para 'inteiro'
d: para 'double'
b: para 'blob'
```

Answer (score 3):

Antes de mais nada, conexões utilizando mysql_connect estão sendo descontinuados pelo PHP, então é recomendado tratar suas conexões utilizando PDO.

Mas, da maneira bruta, seria assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, ... colunaN) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', ... 'valN')";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```