# Como mostrar várias mensagens de erro simultaneamente em formulário?

Tags: php, if, foreach

Eu estou tentando fazer com que minha pagina de registro mostre todas mensagens de campos esquecidos juntas como nesse exemplo:

[image: erros]

Mas ela só mostra em partes:

**1 - "Username already exists" e "Email already exists"**
ou

**2 - "Please insert a username", "Please insert a password" e "Please insert a email"** 
ou

**3 - "Username must have less than 16 characters" e "Password must have 8 or more characters"**

Tem alguma solução pra isso?

```
<?php
$page = "Register";
include "header.php";

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){

    if(strlen($username) < 17 && strlen($password) > 7){

        $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
        $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 0 && mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 0){

            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
            ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
        }
        else{
            if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0){
                $error[] = "Username already exists";
            }
            if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) > 0){
                $error[] = "Email already exists";
            }
            foreach($error as $value){
                ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(strlen($username) > 16){
            $error[] = "Username must have less than 16 characters";
        }
        if(strlen($password) < 8){
            $error[] = "Password must have 8 or more characters";
        }
        foreach($error as $value){
            ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
        }
    }
}
else{

    if(empty($username)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a username";
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a password";
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a email";
    }
    foreach ($error as $value) {
        ?><p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p><?php
    }
}
}
?>

<div id="loginform">
    <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div class="loginheader"><h2>Register</h2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" id="REGOPTIONS">
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" class="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="register" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar variáveis separadas para cada tipo de erro, e indicá-los nos respectivos campos.

Para que as mensagens possam aparecer simultaneamente, refatorei seu código, permitindo o tratamento de cada campo separadamente:

```
<?php
   $page = 'Register';
   include 'header.php';

   $user_error='';
   $mail_error='';
   $pass_error='';

   if( isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      // Tratamento de erros do username:

      if( empty( $username ) ) {
         $user_error = 'Please insert an username';
      } elseif ( strlen( $username ) ) > 16
         $user_error = 'Username must have less than 17 characters';
      } else {
         // Essa linha abaixo é sujeita a SQL Injection, cuidado!
         $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
         if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) > 0) {
            $user_error = 'Username already exists';
         }
      }

      // Tratamento de erros da senha:

      if( empty( $password ) ) {
         $pass_error = 'Please insert a password';
      } elseif( strlen( $password ) < 8 ) {
         $pass_error = 'Password must have 8 or more characters';
      }

      // Tratamento de erros do email:

      if( empty( $email ) ) {
         $mail_error = 'Please insert an email';
      } else {
         // Essa linha abaixo é sujeita a SQL Injection, cuidado!
         $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
         if( mysql_num_rows( $checkemail ) > 0 ){
            $mail_error = 'Email already exists';
         }
      }
   }

   // Se não setamos nenhum erro, e o formulário foi enviado, podemos ir para o insert:
   if empty( $user_error )
   && empty( $mail_error )
   && empty( $pass_error )
   && isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) {
      $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<div id="sucesso">
   <h3>You are registered!</h3>
   <p>(aqui você pode por instruçoes, ou a mensagem que quiser, no caso do sucesso)</p>
</div>
<?php
   } else {
      // caso contrário, mostramos o form, e opcionalmente os erros encontrados:
      $user_error=empty($user_error)?'Username:' : '<b>'.htmlEntities($user_error).'</b>';
      $mail_error=empty($mail_error)?'Email:' : '<b>'.htmlEntities($email_error).'</b>';
      $pass_error=empty($pass_error)?'Password:' : '<b>'.htmlEntities($pass_error).'</b>';
      // O formulario está dentro deste else:
?>

<div id="loginform">
   <form name="loginform" method="post">
      <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div class="loginheader"><h2>Register</h2></div></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" id="REGOPTIONS">
         <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo $user_error; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="username"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo $pass_error; ?></td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="password"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo $mail_error; ?></td>
            <td><input type="email" class="text" name="email"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="register" value="Register" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>

<?php
   } // Fechando o else acima

   include "footer.php";
?>
```

Assim, cada erro será mostrado em seu próprio campo. Esta solução parece adequada para seu caso, pois só ha um erro de cada tipo sendo mostrado ao mesmo tempo no seu código (usuário, senha e email).

Caso queira, os mesmos `if`s podem ser usados e adaptados para aplicar a solução do @Otto, que é boa caso você queira todos os erros apresentados em um bloco só.

Comment: muito bom @Bacco

Comment: @Lukaz11: Veja nesta resposta como usar o `mysqli` para evitar SQL Injection, e problemas com aspas nos campos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14757/70

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><?php echo "'".$value."'<br>"; ?></p>
```

troque por

```
$error =. "<p>".$value."<br></p>";
```

no final do loop echo $error;

Comment: Eu tentei esse código mas não acontece nada.