# Qual a diferença entre `filter_var` e `filter_input`?

Tags: php, mysql, validação

Qual a diferença entre [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) e [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)? Não consigo achar isso em lugar algum, pelo menos não de uma forma que eu entenda.

E como posso substituir `mysql_real_escape_string` por um deles?

```
$password = mysql_real_string($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Funções filter_input e filter_var:

A diferença básica é que o `filter_input` faz o papel do `filter_var`, mas já pegando de uma variável de entrada (como `GET` ou `POST`).

Este código aqui...

```php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$resultado = filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```

faz a mesma coisa que este:

```php
$resultado = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```

Para saber os filtros disponíveis, veja o manual do PHP: **[Tipos de filtro](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)** <sup>(en)</sup>

### Função mysql_real_escape_string:

O `mysql_real_escape_string()` já é pra outra coisa completamente diferente: é para sanitizar os dados para entrada em campos de tabelas MySQL. Sua finalidade é mais específica, mas é uma função obsoleta, assim como todas as da biblioteca `mysql_`.

Para substituir esta última, utilize por exemplo a biblioteca `mysqli`, veja **[esta questão aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14754/)**.

### Em resumo:

- Se você quer filtrar uma variável já existente, use o `filter_var`;
- se for filtrar um `GET` ou `POST`, por exemplo, use o `filter_input`;
- se for filtrar um valor para inserir em MySQL troque a biblioteca do `mysql_real_escape_string` por `mysqli_` com *[bind parameters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14754/)*.

> `filter_input` e `filter_var` não são substitutos para `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Para uma página de Login, Filter_input seria mais adequado?

Comment: @Lukaz11 se você for usar a variável em uma query (SELECT ou INSERT alguma coisa), precisa ser o mysqli_ ou o mysql_real_escape_string. Se for usar pra validar um email para outra coisa (exibir na página), pode ser o filter_(input ou var,. aí o mais adequado depende de onde vem a variável). Nada impede de você usar o filter para validar o email no PHP, e depois usar o mysqli_ para armazenar corretamente. Aí depende muito do seu código. Dê uma olhada no link que eu pus no _bind parameters_ que lá tem uma resposta que explica como usar mysqli.