# ajuda ja tentei de tudo para resolver meu problema com o mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá a todos estou com um problema que não consigo entender nem resolver sou novato em php.
esse código ele insere os dados no banco de dados normal porem da esse erro.

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): 
  Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
```

Código de inserção

```
$insert_data =("INSERT INTO acompanhamento (nome, email, fone, mensagem, date, hora, local, tipoproc, inlineRadioOptions, num_processo) 
VALUES ('".$dados['nome']."', '".$dados['email']."', '".$dados['fone']."','".$dados['mensagem']."','".$dados['date']."','".$dados['hora']."','".$dados['local']."','".$dados['tipoproc']."','".$dados['inlineRadioOptions']."','".$dados['num_processo']."')");

$insert_data = $conn->prepare($insert_data);
$insert_data->execute();
$insert_data->bind_param('ssssssssss', $nome,$email,$fone,$mensagem,$date,$hora,$local,$inlineRadioOptions,$num_processo,$tipoproc);
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Comparando prepare() vs query() com mysqli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47437/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Inserir dados no banco ultilizando mysqli](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14754/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo valido:

```php
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
```

Em `VALUES` vc so precisava colocar os `?` placeholders pra fazer o bind depois.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado consegui muito obrigado mesmo, só substitui os value por ??? e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo aconselho compartilhar um pouco mais do seu código, mas basicamente o erro é que você está passando onze argumentos no INSERT e no teu bindPrepare tem dez.

Tente fazer algo semelhante a este exemplo:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name, address, salary) VALUES (:name, :address, :salary)";`

$pdo->prepare($sql);
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $param_name);
$stmt->bindParam(":address", $param_address);
$stmt->bindParam(":salary", $param_salary);
$stmt->execute();